# mouse over and mouse out. Collapse content header when hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get a simple collapse on a content header that has list items below it.  Currently the JavaScript I am using is set to onClick.  I want to change this to mouseOver (to expand) and mouseOut (to go back to collapse). [Here is the JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XTtqt/).

I don't know much about JavaScript yet, but I am working on it.  Thanks.

```
function headerClicked(headerObj) {
  if ($(headerObj).parent().find('.contentList').css('display') == 'none') $(headerObj).parent().find('.contentList').slideDown(300);
  else $(headerObj).parent().find('.contentList').slideUp(300);
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XTtqt/4/

Comment: Just use css :hover to show and hide the children.

Comment: BTW you don't need javascript for this: http://jsfiddle.net/XTtqt/7/

Comment: @Malk true, but if he needs some animations that are cross browser supported then he _needs_ to use _JavaScript_ (for IE9 or less support).

Comment: @Vucko, there is a lot you can do with just CSS so 'needs to use' might be extreme. I am not trying to say CSS can perform all that JS can, but it is getting close! http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using JQuery, why not add an event handler to react when the mouse get's on or leaves the header? You can do this with the mouse mouseout function from JQuery.

You can write something like this for when the mouse leaves

```
$(".header").mouseout(function(e){
    $(e.currentTarget).parent().find('.contentList').slideUp(300)
})
```

The docs are here http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/ and http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of solutions of your problem. e.g it can be handled easily using jQuery hover 
http://api.jquery.com/hover/ . But for this time, the simplest solution can be the following one...

http://jsfiddle.net/r486Y/

Here, instead of using 'onClick' function I have used two functions, one for 'onmouseover' and another one for 'onmouseleave' the functions are as following...

```
function headerClicked(headerObj) { 
       $(headerObj).parent().find('.contentList').slideDown(300);
} 
function headerClickedUp(headerObj) { 
       $(headerObj).parent().find('.contentList').slideUp(300);
}
```

Do not forget to add

```
.contentList
{
    display:none;
}
```

to the css to hide the '' at the time of page loading.

**To use it as drop down list** reorder it as following...

http://jsfiddle.net/69gNB/

Comment: Much better, however when I do the onMouseLeave on the header will not allow me to scroll down to the list items.  Do I apply he onMouseLeave on the <ul> tag?

Comment: It is only working on the header...so, when you leave mouse from header it is sliding up

Comment: I think now you can have your desired result, follow this one http://jsfiddle.net/69gNB/